# Wordpress twitter bootstrap image carousel from specific category

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm using the Bootstrap theme from 320press and currently struggling with the image slider carousel. It displays the posts of every featured image on the site, when I just want a specific category. I guess it's the following code I have to tweak som way...?

```
<?php
global $post;
$tmp_post = $post;
$show_posts = of_get_option('slider_options');
$args = array( '2' => $show_posts ); // set this to how many posts you want in the carousel
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
$post_num = 0;
foreach( $myposts as $post ) :  setup_postdata($post);
    $post_num++;
    $post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id();
    $featured_src = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $post_thumbnail_id, 'wpbs-featured-carousel' );
?>
```

Comment: Where are you getting that code?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. Thought it was from the original GitHub code for page-homepage.php. More here: http://pastie.org/8719608

Comment: The arguments to get_posts() don't look correct.

Comment: Well, it works at least.

Comment: I don't think the arguments are working - since they're invalid, they're probably being ignored and all posts are being returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try replacing the `$args` for `get_posts()` with the following.  You'll need to put in the slug of the category that you want to show.  Since I don't know exactly how this plugin works, I can't guarantee it'll work as expected.

`$args = array(
  'posts_per_page' => $show_posts,
  'category_name' => 'your_category_slug'
);`

You can see a complete list of the arguments available for `get_posts()` on the WP_Query page of the WordPress codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query.

I'm a little confused by the counter that your code is setting.  It seems like setting the number of posts to fetch as an argument to `get_posts()` would make a lot more sense.